# Rolling count in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to get the following ratio (daily sign up count)/(last 30 days rolling sign up count for each day)

The daily numbers are straight forward

```
SELECT a.DailySignup
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(1) AS DailySignup, date
FROM users
WHERE date BETWEEN datestart and dateend
GROUP BY date
) a
```

but how can I compute the last 30 days count for each day? I know I need to join it against the same table again but I cant seem to wrap my head around it as to how.

**UPDATE**
Sorry I've not been very clear.

```
SIGNUP_COUNT DATE          Rolling_Signup_Count
10           2011-01-01    Sign ups from 2010-12-01 to 2011-01-01
12           2011-01-02    Sign ups from 2010-12-02 to 2011-01-02
4            2011-01-03    Sign ups from 2010-12-03 to 2011-01-03
```

Hope this table helps to illustrate what I mean by rolling sign up count

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "last 30 days count for each day"? Is it the mean daily count over the last 30 days (that is, the total signup over the last 30 days dividid by 30)? Please give the mathematical definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.date, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users u where u.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(t.date, INTERVAL -30 day) AND t.date) as c 
FROM users t
```

For a given date t.date, the subquery calculates the count for the 30-day period ending with t.date.

EDIT: To calculate the ratio (logins per day)/(logins within 30 days), you could try

```
SELECT t.date, count(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users u 
       WHERE u.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(t.date, INTERVAL -30 day) AND t.date) as c 
FROM users t GROUP BY t.date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `MONTH(date)` to get for each month, try something like this:

```
SELECT a.DailySignup, month AS MONTH(date)
FROM users
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS DailySignup, MONTH(date) AS month
            FROM users
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
) a ON a.month = month
    GROUP BY month
```